# C HTTP uriparser lib setup

Tags: c, http, libraries, url-parsing

I am currently working on a simple HTTP proxy as an educational personal project. I am fairly new to socket programming, C, and the need for and use of specific libraries.

After reading up on different ways to parse HTTP request URLs in C, I found that using parsing libraries, like **uriparser**, seemed to be the most popular and the safest choice.

Unfortunately, I have really been struggling to get this library working properly.

After downloading the library from [here](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/), I unpacked the "tarball" and ran the following:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The output for 'sudo make install' claimed that that the libraries were installed in '/usr/local/lib', which they have been. However, when I try to use a  UriUriA obj as shown in Uriparser's documentation [here](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/doc/html/#intro), the object is clearly not recognized.

Is this library installed in the right place?

Am I missing something obvious like not including a header file for this library? I could't find one in the linked documentation.

**RELEVANT CODE:**

(functionality is pretty bare right now, mainly pointing at UriUri instantiation which still produces unknown type compile error. I still have yet to be able to use the lib)

```
int parse_req(char * buffer, char * url){
    UriUriA uri;
    char *reqs[] = {"GET ", "CONNECT "};
    int i = 0;

    //Determine Request Types
    while(reqs[i] != NULL){
        int check = strncmp(reqs[i],buffer,strlen(reqs[i]));
        if (check == 0){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If anyone has any experience with this library, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us your code which is attempting to use the `uriparser` library?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited and put up some relevant code. As noted,  my parse_req function is pretty bare right now. I still have yet to be able to use the library, and more so am having trouble linking it I guess?

Comment: Yes, it looks like your code will need an `#include <Uri.h>`, and build instructions to include the `include/` directory of the install path.  You can see this in the `test/test.cpp` file in the source tarball.